# Парсинг картинок с сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-скрейпинг

Делаю парсинг сайта `Domain.com`. Я достаю ссылки на картинки(которые расположены на `images.domain.com`), но на прямую я не могу смотреть или что либо делать с ними, они доступны только на сайте, или при шаринге с него в Телеграмм или Фейсбук. Объясните пожалуйста, что это вообще такое и можно ли как то добраться до этих картинок?

Comment: referer попробуйте добавить подходящий

Comment: Не ясен контекст. Ты скачать их хочешь ?

Comment: да, до этого я получал html, искал картинки и просто скачивал, но сейчас что-то поменялось. Я скачиваю все картинки в мобильное приложение.

Comment: Покажите пример ссылки на картинку.

Comment: Проблема было в referer. Поигрался с ним и все получилось , всем большое спасибо за помощь))

Comment: @grooby вы бы хоть свое решение выложили, если можно, может кому и пригодится еще

Comment: Я просто добавил referer и все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавай правильные `referer`, `user-agent` и куки.